# Magento options not shown on order, invoice (database not populated)

Tags: magento

After upgrading to Magento 1.6.2.0 (from 1.4) the **product_option** field in table **sales_flat_order_item** doesn’t get updated when a new order is placed.

In the older orders before the upgrade the entry shows as:

> a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest”;a:3:{s:7:"options";a:2… etc.

but after the upgrade:

> a:0:{}

I’ve tried switching to standard template, adding new test product with options, removing extensions to no avail.

Perhaps someone knows how the **product_options** field is populated?

The option values are inserted into **sales_flat_quote_item_option** when the product is added to the basket, but not to **sales_flat_order_item** when the actual order is placed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experienced this issue after upgrades, but here are some pointers that hopefully will help you pinpoint the issue and provide a little background information.

The conversion from quote item to order item is handled by `Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote::itemToOrderItem()`.

This is how the product options are copied.

```
$options = $item->getProductOrderOptions();
if (!$options) {
    $options = $item->getProduct()
        ->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
}
$orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
```

The `getOrderOptions()` fetches the options array from the product, including the `info_buyRequest` and any selected attribute options.

The composite product handling has been unified with Magento 1.5. Any options, regardless if they are configurable product options, bundled product configurations, or custom options, all are handled by the same composite products subsystem.

These changes also aimed at keeping backward compatibility as far as possible, but some extensions that override deep core functionality have to be upgraded to work with the new process.

To find out if there are any rewrites in place that change classes in question, I'd run the following code to check the catalog and sales module.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

print_r(array(
    'Mage_Catalog Model Rewrites' => Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/models/catalog/rewrite'),
    'Mage_Sales Model Rewrites'   => Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/models/sales/rewrite')
));
```

If product type models, sales order or quote items or sales convert or service models are rewritten, try disabling those extensions.

Comment: Thank you very much Vinai for taking the time to write this excellent educational explanation. Turns out that app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Convert/order.php and quote.php (found after searching for Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote) was being rewritten by a long-ago forgotten, not properly uninstalled, extension to create custom invoices.